# Accessing data/app fails despite granted su permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions, root

Currently I am trying to get a quick overview of all installed apps on my phone by creating a ListView based on a string array consisting of all files contained within the data/app & system/app directories:

My code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

Process p;
try {
   // Preform su to get root privledges
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

   // Attempt to write a file to a root-only
   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
   os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/sd/temporary.txt\n");

   // Close the terminal
   os.writeBytes("exit\n");
   os.flush();
   try {
      p.waitFor();
           if (p.exitValue() != 255) {
                File dir = new File("./system/app");
                File dir2 = new File("./data/app");
                String[] values = this.both(dir.list(), dir2.list());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
           }
           else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "not root", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "not root", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "not root", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

(taken from http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/)

The both method looks as follows:

```
  private String[] both(String[] first, String[] second) {
    List<String> both = new ArrayList<String>(first.length + second.length);
    Collections.addAll(both, first);
    Collections.addAll(both, second);
    return both.toArray(new String[both.size()]);
  }
```

However, my application keeps crashing. By removing the respective part of the code I was able to find out the reason is indeed the "new File("./data/app");" part.

Comment: you can easily get this info using packagemanager rather than listing the apps from directories

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the respective API. Nevertheless I would like to have a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running

> p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

you are creating a new process which will have root access. But your application runs in a different process. So your applcation will not have root access.

One way is to use chmod on /data/app to give permission to your app and then revert it back to original after dir.list() is over.

```
os.writeBytes("chmod 744 \data\app \n");
os.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears that this was indeed the problem! Can you tell me what the original permissions were?